# Error when writing to Microsoft SQL server with RODBC on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, rodbc

I am using `RODBC` to connect to a Microsoft SQL database using on an Ubuntu environment.  Rather than connecting to the server/instance using `odbcConnect` (which I understand is recommended), I have written a custom connection string that I pass to `odbcDriverConnect`:

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("driver=", driver,";server=", host,";database=", dbname,";uid=", user, ";pwd=", password))
```

The command:

```
datatable <- sqlQuery(con, proccall)
```

where `proccall` contains a stored procedure name in the database works like a charm. When I try to reproduce the following example from the documentation for `sqlSave`, however, using the same `con`, I get the following error:

```
sqlSave(con, USArrests, rownames = "state", addPK=TRUE)

Error in sqlSave(con, USArrests, rownames = "state", addPK = TRUE) : 
  42000 102 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'USArrests'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE "USArrests"  ("state" varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "Murder" float, "Assault" int, "UrbanPop" int, "Rape" float)'
```

An attempt to test write `mtcars` similarly fails:

```
sqlSave(con, mtcars, rownames = TRUE, colnames = FALSE) 

Error in sqlSave(con, mtcars, rownames = TRUE, colnames = FALSE) : 
  42000 102 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'mtcars'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE "mtcars"  ("rownames"  varchar(255), "mpg" float, "cyl" float, "disp" float, "hp" float, "drat" float, "wt" float, "qsec" float, "vs" float, "am" float, "gear" float, "carb" float)
```

I've read the documentation and it's not at all clear to me what's going on here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Apparently very few people on the internet care about this one, but it appears to be a permissions issue. Will post an update once I have it.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having the same problem

Comment: Not really :/ What ended up working for me was nagging this customer to create a DSN which I passed to odbcConnect. This was a lot more stable than working with odbcDriverConnect. I never did figure out what was happening with sqlSave. If you solve it please come back and let us know!